# UIModalPresentationFormSheet is not shown in iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller which works perfectly in iPhone.

But when I present it in iPad with UIModalPresentationFormSheet style, it is blank. Nothing is inside it.

When I show it without setting Presentation style, it is shown perfectly. I use following codes:

```
[viewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
viewController.view.superview.bounds = viewController.view.frame;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

What would be problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Why this: viewController.view.superview.bounds = viewController.view.frame;

Comment: to set the frame. however removing it doesn't help me!

Comment: First: you definitely shouldn't be monkeying with the controller's parent views (though it isn't likely to have any before it's been presented). Second: are you sure that both `viewController` and `self.navigationController` are non-`nil`?

Comment: Yes I am sure. they are not!